# Does Google Pub/Sub feature have some of capability to notify a Google App Engine endpoint directly after an upload?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking at the documentation for Google Pub/Sub ( https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications ) and I don't see a way for Pub/Sub to make a RESTful call to a Google App Engine endpoint when a new file has been uploaded to a bucket.

Is this correct, or did I miss something?

It says in the documentation that there is an older way to probably accomplish this : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification . But I am not sure if it is a good idea to use something that might be deprecated down the line?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use a cloud function as an intermediary then? Have it call your endpoint when a change event is thrown?

Comment: Hi @DriesDeRydt , thanks for the reply, cloud function looks like it might work, but do you also have any opinion on using Object Change Notification? It seems to do what Google PubSub and Cloud Function's job in one step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCS's Cloud Pub/Sub support works well for this case.

First, create a Cloud Pub/Sub topic and configure your GCS bucket to send it `OBJECT_FINALIZE` messages. You can do so like this:

```
$> gsutil notification create -f json \
       -t newTopicName \
       -e OBJECT_FINALIZE \
       gs://bucketName
```

Next, add a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to your Cloud Pub/Sub topic which pushes notifications to your App Engine endpoint. You can do this in the UI, or you can run a command like this:

```
$> gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions create subscriptionName \
        --topic newTopicName \
        --push-endpoint https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/push_handlers/myHandler
```

Finally, configure your app engine app to handle incoming push events at that URL. You can read more about this approach in Cloud Pub/Sub's documentation: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#app-engine-standard-endpoints

Comment: Hi @brandon-yarbrough , thanks for the answer. I am also curious on two things regarding using GCS along with Google Pub/Sub. Are there cases at scale when a GCS event fails to hit the Pub/Sub topic or the PubSub topic notification fails to get pushed to the receiving AppEngine URL? Thanks

Comment: Theoretically no. GCS guarantees that you'll get get a notification for every event at least once, eventually. That said, accidents happen. You could accidentally deploy a version of your app with a bug that doesn't handle messages right, or Google could mess up, or you could decide you want to store things differently, or Google's delivery could be delayed. It's always a good idea with workflows like this to periodically list the bucket's contents and verify that they're in sync with your app, just in case.

Comment: Hi @brandon-yarbrough , yea, I decided to test out the GCS to pubsub topic to appengine endpoint setup, and I noticed that the pubsub topic seems to ignore the acknowledgment deadline that I set (in seconds). If it push-notifications to the endpoint and gets like a 403, it will keep retrying immediately. I actually thought that it would wait for the amount of time specified by acknowledgement deadline.

Comment: When you respond with a 403, you are explicitly NACKing the message, and so Pub/Sub will immediately try again. The acknowledgement deadline is for handling timeouts (for example, when your server doesn't respond at all). See https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push.